# Return a list of matches based on one variable 1 in R

Tags: r

I have 2 data frames and I want to find matches in the second one based on a variable from the first one:

```
ID<-c(1:10)
year<-c(2012,2015,2012,2019,2010,2020,2013,2015,2017,2013)

df1<-tibble(ID,year)

ID2<-c(20:49)
year2<-c(2010,2019,2020,2012,2010,2015,2012,2012,2013,2020,2019,2015,2015,2019,2020,2012,2013,2015,2016,2017,2016,2012,2019,2020,2018,2012,2010,2018,2010,2012)
diff_years<-c(2,0,0,1,3,4,2,2,3,0,8,2,3,1,2,1,2,4,2,9,1,0,4,1,0,3,0,5,3,3)

df2<-tibble(ID2,year2,diff_years)
```

I want to randomly match one observation from df2 to each observation in df1 based on the year. The observations in df2 cannot be used twice. However, I want to give higher priority to rows with the variable "diff_years" of 2 or more years. For example, could you make it so you chose a value of diff_years >=2 with a probability of .8? The output would ideally return a list of potential matches from df2, like this:

```
  
ID   year2  diff_years
26   2012      2
31   2015      2
23   2012      1
30   2019      8
24   2010      3
34   2020      2
36   2013      2
37   2015      4
39   2017      9
28   2013      3
```

I have tried the Matchit package and can do the exact match based on the year if I combine the data frames:

```
m.out <- matchit(treat ~ year, data = data,exact = "year", ratio=1)
```

However I cannot figure out how to apply the second condition. Is there a way to do this just using dplyr or base? Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work for you.  First step is to split df2 into a list of data frames for each year.  Then shuffle the original order.
Once that is completed, one can then select the first row of the data frame from the newly shuffle list.  Once a particular row was selected, remove it from the shuffled data frame.

See comments for more details.

```
df1<-structure(list(ID = 1:10, 
                    year = c(2012, 2015, 2012, 2019, 2010, 2020, 2013, 2015, 2017, 2013)), 
               class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))

df2<-structure(list(ID2 = 20:49, 
                    year2 = c(2010, 2019, 2020, 2012, 2010, 2015, 2012, 2012, 2013, 2020, 2019, 2015, 2015, 2019, 2020, 
                              2012, 2013, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2016, 2012, 2019, 2020, 2018, 2012, 2010, 2018, 2010, 2012), 
                    diff_years = c(2, 0, 0, 1, 3, 4, 2, 2, 3, 0, 8, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 2, 9, 1, 0, 4, 1, 0, 3, 0, 5, 3, 3)), 
               class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -30L))

library(dplyr)
set.seed(123)
#split the df2 into a list by years
mylist <- split(df2, df2$year2)

#randomly shuffle each years of daga
shuffledlist <- lapply(mylist, function(df){
   #addjust the sample to meet your needs
   shuffle <- sample(1:nrow(df), nrow(df))
   #add more probalitiy when diff years >= 2
   #shuffle <- sample(1:nrow(df), nrow(df), prob=ifelse(df$diff_years>1, 2, 1))
   #shuffle orignial data frame
   df[shuffle, ]
})

#step through each row of first data frame
answer <- lapply(1:nrow(df1), function(i) {
   #retrieve the correct year from list
   data <- shuffledlist[[as.character(df1$year[i])]]
   #take the first row from the shuffle data frame
   outputrow <- data[1,]
   #remove the first row and store it back into shuffled data frame
   shuffledlist[[as.character(df1$year[i])]] <<- data[-1,]
   
   outputrow
})

#make the final answer
answer <- bind_rows(answer)
answer
# A tibble: 10 × 3
    ID2 year2 diff_years
  <int> <dbl>      <dbl>
1    27  2012          2
2    25  2015          4
3    26  2012          2
4    21  2019          0
5    46  2010          0
6    43  2020          1
7    36  2013          2
8    31  2015          2
9    39  2017          9
10    28  2013          3
```